# Aggregation of daily correlations to different frequencies

Tags: regression, time-series, correlation, aggregation, midas

After using the DCC-GARCH model to find the estimated correlations between 2 time series, I would like to perform linear regression with these daily correlations as my dependent variable and test the influential significance of several independent variables (ex: CPI, long term interest rate ...).

The problem is that the correlations are of daily frequency, while the independent variables are of monthly and yearly frequency. A suggestion from my professor is to aggregate the daily correlations to monthly and yearly frequency to perform the regression, but I can not seem to figure out how to do it.

What is an effective way of performing this procedure?

Comment: If you have sufficiently long time series, you could run your DCC-GARCH model on monthly data. Then you would have matching data frequencies for your dependent and independent variables.

Comment: @RichardHardy thank you for your comment. It seems that I forgot to add this issue to my question. Our monthly data has 235 observations which should be sufficiently long. However, there seems to be no ARCH effect when using monthly data, while this problem does not occur when using daily data.

Comment: @RichardHardy thank you again for the explanation. Unfortunately, my knowledge of GARCH models and the software R is limited. After doing research for quite some time now, I find there is little 'understandable' information about this model for students who have limited knowledge.

My professor recommended to aggregate the daily correlations into monthly frequencies. Perhaps because she knows our knowledge about statistics is limited. Could this aggregation give a plausible solution according to you? Do you know a way to apply this aggregation to get the monthly values?

Comment: I think that conceptually the monthly DCC model is a more straightforward way for obtaining monthly conditional correlations than your approach. However, I understand the challenges with software implementations. So if you stick to your daily DCC model, I guess you could take the average of the fitted daily values for a given month as your estimate of the conditional correlation for that month. But again, conceptually I would expect more sensible results from a monthly DCC model (though thinking about estimation precision, 235 observations are not much for such a model).

Comment: What do you think about my answer? If it is helpful and clear, you may accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left. Otherwise, you may ask for further clarification. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

If you have sufficiently long time series, you could run your DCC model on monthly data. Then you would have matching data frequencies for your dependent and independent variables.

> However, there seems to be no ARCH effect when using monthly data, while this problem does not occur when using daily data.

Even if there are no ARCH patterns in monthly data, there might still be DCC patterns there. Note that in principle the DCC model can take any univariate conditional variance model as an input; it does not have to be GARCH. However, some software implementations (such as the `rmgarch` package in R) only allow univariate GARCH inputs to DCC. In such a case you may either create a fake object of the appropriate GARCH class but with constant conditional variance or use a GARCH model with restricted parameter values, e.g. $\alpha=0.001$ and $\beta=0.999$ that will produce a virtually constant conditional variance.